# How to prevent context menu from popping up if clicking on empty space inside a QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, contextmenu, qtableview

I have created a context menu on a `QTableView`, for this I have implemented a custom `contextMenuEvent()` method (because I have a second `QTableview` for which I will implement another context menu later).

What I want is the context menu (on `table_1`) to popup *only if clicking on a row*. Sometimes there are just a few rows and so there is empty space below the last row. And if I right-click there the context menu appears, because it's attached to the whole table.

Since in my case a value is required for performing an action properly (i.e. deleting a folder in a directory) and because `get_selected_item()` of course returns `None` as long as there's no row selected, I just added the following to the `delete_file()` method:

```python
def delete_file(self):
    if item is not None:
        # then do something
```

But this is just a workaround to avoid an exception (i.e a `File not found` error, because `None` is being returned when clicking on empty space).

My question is, how to make the context menu popup *only if I click on a row*?

**This is my code:**

```python
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *



data_1 = ["file_name", "file_infos"]
data_2 = ["other_stuff", "stuff_infos"]


class TableView_1(QTableView):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.contextMenu = QMenu(self)

        deleteAction = QAction("Delete", self)
        self.contextMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
        deleteAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.delete_file(event))

        self.contextMenu.popup(QCursor.pos())

    def get_selected_item(self):
        # get the row's text from the first column in table_1
        listed_items = self.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for index in listed_items:
            selected_item = index.data()
            return f"'{selected_item}' at row: '{index.row()}' from 'table_1'"

    def delete_file(self, event):
        item = self.get_selected_item()

        if item is not None:
            print(f"[INFO]: Deleting {item}")



class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("MyApp")
        self.resize(450, 280)
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)

        #]===================================================================[#

        # table_1
        table_1 = TableView_1(
            centralwidget,
            selectionBehavior=QAbstractItemView.SelectRows,
            editTriggers=QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers
        )
        # table_1 models
        self.modelTV1 = QStandardItemModel(0, 2, centralwidget)
        self.modelTV1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["column 1", "column 2"])
        table_1.setModel(self.modelTV1)

        #]===================================================================[#

        # table_2
        table_2 = QTableView(
            centralwidget,
            selectionBehavior=QAbstractItemView.SelectRows,
            editTriggers=QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers,
        )
        # table_2 models
        self.modelTV2 = QStandardItemModel(0, 2, centralwidget)
        self.modelTV2.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["column 1", "column 2"])
        table_2.setModel(self.modelTV2)

        v_Layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        v_Layout1.addWidget(table_1)
        v_Layout1.addWidget(table_2)
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        gridLayout.addLayout(v_Layout1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)


    def populate_table_1(self):
        self.modelTV1.setRowCount(0)
        for item in data_1:
            self.modelTV1.insertRow(0)
            for i, text in enumerate(data_1):
                self.modelTV1.setItem(0, i, QStandardItem(text))


    def populate_table_2(self):
        self.modelTV2.setRowCount(0)
        for item in data_2:
            self.modelTV2.insertRow(0)
            for i, text in enumerate(data_2):
                self.modelTV2.setItem(0, i, QStandardItem(text))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainUI = Ui_MainWindow()

    mainUI.populate_table_1()
    mainUI.populate_table_2()
    mainUI.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use `if self.indexAt(event.pos()).isValid(): ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc That works. It was exactely what I was looking for.